# Show that the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts that are all $m$ or less is

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Full problem: Show that the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts that are all $m$ or less is the number of partitions of $km-n$ into fewer than $m$ parts that are all $k$ or less.

I'm a little confused about how to show this, I tried drawing a Ferrer's diagram, because it's reminding me a little but of identifying self-conjugate partitions but I'm not sure... Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I think it should be "partitions of $n$ into $k$ OR LESS parts"?

Comment: @Dzoooks no, it's just into k parts!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Consider the $k \times m$ rectangle into which the partition diagrams of both types fit and find a bijection between the two types:

$$\begin{matrix} {\color{red} \bullet} &{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet} \\ {\color{red} \bullet} &{\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{blue} \bullet}&{\color{blue} \bullet} \\ {\color{red} \bullet} & {\color{red} \bullet} &{\color{blue} \bullet} &{\color{blue} \bullet} \\ {\color{red} \bullet}& {\color{blue} \bullet}& {\color{blue} \bullet} &{\color{blue} \bullet}\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I'm just a bit unclear on how this rectangle counts both of the number of necessary partitions.. What is the relation supposed to be between km and n?

Comment: $n$ is the size of the red partition.  $km-n$ is the size of the blue partition.  Just do it for a few examples.

Comment: I see it with examples, but to word it properly- If we take a $k•m$ rectangle, and remove the a partition of size $n$ that is $k$ parts, size $m$ or less, then the remaining area is exactly partitioned into fewer than $m$ parts that are k or less.

Comment: So there is a bijection between those two types of partitions